# В каком типе хранить и как выводить баланс?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно записать в базу MySQL запись о балансе. Баланс не может быть отрицательный, то есть - минимум = 0.

Но есть два типа валюты, это usd/rub и coin (биткойн например).
Так вот, у типа usd/rub должно быть цифры после точки, а у coin - 10 цифр после точки.

Создал ячейку типа **decimal(11,10)**. 
как на выводе выводить только 4 цифры после точки?

P.S. я думаю просто сделать условие, если coin - выводить с базы баланс как есть, если  usd/rub - выводить только 4 цифры после точки.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

////////////

```
 $sql_opt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `valuta` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
 while ($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_opt)) {
   echo $sql['balance'];
 }
```

Comment: для финансовых работ я бы посоветовал Long (bigint) и самому определить разряд. Можно создать функцию который конвертирует туда и другой обратно. decimal тоже можно, только для вывода нужно формат указать

Comment: *для финансовых работ я бы посоветовал Long (bigint) и самому определить разряд.* А какой великий смысл искать себе геморрою? DECIMAL, как и BIGINT - точный тип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как на выводе выводить только 4 цифры после точки?
>
> P.S. я думаю просто сделать условие, если coin - выводить с базы баланс как есть, если usd/rub - выводить только 4 цифры после точки.

```
CASE WHEN currency = 'coin' THEN balance ELSE ROUND(balance, 4) END AS balance
```

**UPDATE**

> вставил в вопрос свой кусок кода. можете на основе его подставить?

```
 $sql_opt = mysql_query("SELECT *, CASE WHEN currency = 'coin' THEN balance ELSE ROUND(balance, 4) END AS rounded_balance FROM `valuta` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
 while ($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_opt)) {
   echo $sql['rounded_balance'];
 }
```

Comment: не совсем понял как применить ваш запрос. я просто циклом вывожу все из базы, типа `while ($sql = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_opt)) {` и потом просто **$sql['balance'];**

Comment: Вместо поля `balance` в выходной набор вставляете указанное выражение. ВСЁ.

Comment: хм.. все равное не пойму что вы хотите донести.. вставил в вопрос свой кусок кода. можете на основе его подставить?

Comment: @Денис *вставил в вопрос свой кусок кода* Исправьте текст запроса и замените звёздочку на список выводимых полей.

Comment: а поля нужно вывести все... что-то у меня ошибки синтакс. выдает...

Comment: @Денис По хорошему все поля и надо перечислить... но коли лень обуяла, используйте код, добавленный в ответ.

Comment: все отлично. благодарю!